# I have this Python code that is supposed to generate a key and i cant execute the program on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I tried to run this code using both Python and Python 3 on my machine, but it has many errors such as:

```
python3 gen.py
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/gen.py", line 1, in <module>
    from crypto.Cipher import DES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crypto'
```

And:

```
python gen.py
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import DES
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
```

#### Code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
import binascii

key = open('key').read()
iv = '55531056'
cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_OFB, iv)
plaintext = open('plain.txt').read()
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
with open('flag.enc', 'w') as f:
    f.write(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the package called `crypto`.
Install it and execute your program again:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) is an abandoned project, I don't recommend anybody to use it, there's [`pycryptodome`](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) which is a compatible replacement.